# How to provide animation in an owner-drawn menu item?

Tags: .net, animation, menu, contextmenu, ownerdrawn

My application is in C# 3.5, Winforms, but this will most likely require P/Invoke anyway, so it's not that strictly tied to .NET.

I have created owner-drawn menu items via `ContextMenu` and `MenuItem` classes. All works well, but for some items I'd like to create a little animation (showing that there is a process running, associated with the item). Unfortunately the above mentioned two classes do not provide an `Invalidate()` method or anything similar.

My best idea so far is to P/Invoke `WindowFromDC()` on the first OnDraw, save the resulting handle, and then periodically call `InvalidateRect()` on the handle, until the menu is closed.

This seems kinda hackish though, I haven't tried it yet, and wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `WindowFromDC`, I might suggest calling the [`GetMenuItemRect` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647981.aspx) to retrieve the bounding rectangle for a particular menu item. Then, you can pass the [rectangle structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162897.aspx) filled by that function to the [`InvalidateRect` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002.aspx).

I agree that this solution has somewhat of a "hackish" feel to it, but I suspect that's because the menus provided by the Windows API were not designed to be animated. The menu wrapper classes provided by the .NET Framework don't include an `Invalidate` function because this is a relatively rare use case. Generally, it's sufficient for owner-drawn menu items to change each time the pop-up menu is displayed (by handling the [`WM_INITMENUPOPUP` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646347.aspx)). As far as I know, the above proposal is the most "correct" way that there is to do what you want.

If you really need that much control over drawing menus, you might be one of the few people for whom the cheesy `MenuStrip`/`ContextMenuStrip` classes are actually better. Since they're implemented entirely in managed code, the `ToolStripItem` class provides a working [`Invalidate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0x791wd.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but they have problems with being fully ownerdrawn. At least thats what people were saying on the net, and I couldn't get to paint it all either. In my case I'm doing some pretty heavy customization - two lines of text in different fonts; big preferably animated icon; maybe something else. The menu items aren't even all the same height (some have just one line of text).

Comment: @Vilx: Hmm, that's interesting. To be honest, I'm really not much of an owner-draw guy. I've done plenty of owner-drawing of the standard menus to get icons (groan), but I've removed `MenuStrip` and its buddies from my toolbox altogether. What I've read online seems to indicate that they provide *better* customizability/owner-draw support than the API menus. Their major merit is they are properly architected and actually object-oriented, which means you can subclass `ToolStripItem` and do your own drawing as required. You probably tried to subclass `ToolStripMenuItem`, which is more limited.

Comment: Ahh, might be. I really did try to subclass `ToolStripMenuItem`. But can a `ContextMenuStrip` contain items other than `ToolStripMenuItem`?

Comment: @Vilx: I don't actually know. It inherits its [`Items` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.items.aspx) directly from the `ToolStrip` control, which returns a `ToolStripItemCollection`. So in theory, yes. But I'm not certain that it isn't *expecting* a certain subclass of `ToolStripItem`. Sometimes, people get OOP wrong. ;-)